# Flink - how to aggregate and query a rich sink functions state across multiple task slots

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-consumer-api, flink-streaming

I implemented a rich sink function which performs some network calls per the invoked upon object. I would like to be able to count some metadata on these events keyed by some contextual information contained on the event (a batchID of the event), and expose this meta data to external system.

For example an event looks like this:

```
case class MyEvent(batchId: String, eventId: String, moreInformation: ...)

class MySink(...) extends RichSinkFunction[MyEvent] 
{
override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    ...
  }

  override def close(): Unit = {
    ...
  }

  override def invoke(event: MyEvent) = {
    // some processing is done here

    ....
   //
   ...
     if (success) {
        I want to save the meta data here per event.batchId
        state.count.number.of.events.processed.for.event.batchId
     }
  }
}
```

And in another place I want to somehow be able to query the value of how many events were processed for batchId

Answer (score 0):

A few options:

Plan A: Use Metric objects and a MetricReporter to expose the data to the external system(s). This has the drawback that metrics aren't checkpointed, and if there are a lot of batchIds, you'll probably end up polluting the metrics system with lots of metrics that can't get GC'ed.

Plan B: Rewrite your RichSinkFunction as a RichFlatMap (or ProcessFunction) that emits a stream of Tuples holding (batchId, number.of.events.in.batchId). You can key this stream by the batchId, and then use keyed state in a KeyedProcessFunction (for example) to store and expose this state via queryable state. This has the drawback that queryable state only allows for point queries (one key at a time).

Plan C: In this variant, the external systems could query the state created in Plan B by injecting queries into a stream that is broadcast into a KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction that holds keyed state.count.number.of.events.processed.for.event.batchId data. You can then use ctx.applyToKeyedState in the processBroadcastElement method of the KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction to respond to these queries. See [one of the Flink training exercises](https://training.data-artisans.com/exercises/ongoingRides.html) for an example.

Plan D: write the results from B (or C) into redis, or elasticsearch, or some other queryable data store, and have the external systems get this info from there.